# Browser Like Tabs for an iFrame web browser

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am developing a fun little project which is an iframe browser. The browser functions very well but the problem is, I can't seem to get tabs correctly. What I want for tabs is a remove and add function.
Will someone kindly help me out.

By the way my project can be found here: https://bird-pack.ml/lol/

Comment: What have you tried so far to get tabs?

Comment: I have tried using DOM but its not adding any tab buttons :/

Comment: This is far too open ended to be answered on SO, as this will lead to opinionated answers (generally out of scope for SO).